# How to assign array values to double variable

Tags: ios, arrays, double

I have to assign array values to double variable.If i do like this,
it shows an error -

> Initializing 'double' with incompatible type 'id'.

my code:

```
NSArray *units =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"20",@"4.0",@" 6.0",@"3.0",@" 12.0",@" 16.0",nil ];

 for (int i = 0; i < units.count; i++)
    {
        double yvalue = units[0];
        NSLog(@"val:%f",yvalue);
        [yVals addObject:[[ChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:yvalue xIndex:i]];
    }
```

Comment: just cast the return value of `units[0]` to double

Comment: static NSString *tempString = nil;   for (int i = 0; i < units.count; i++)
    { tempString = units[0]; double yvalue = [tempString doubleValue]; } just replace the the for loop like this to get doubleValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are assigning string to double directly. 
You need to cast string to double as following:

`double yvalue = [units[0] doubleValue];`

Answer (score 0):

Just cast object using doubleValue

```
 double yvalue =[units[0] doubleValue];
```